# SharePoint REST Api returns empty data in Postman

Tags: rest, sharepoint, postman, sharepoint-online

I am using the SharePoint REST API to get the data, but it returns the empty data in Postman. When I put the same url in browser there I can see number of items were returned. any suggestions?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUOPJ.png)

Comment: Please, add image prove that it works on browser, and correct request info in dev tools, so people can have more info to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be something wrong in App's Permission Request XML
Please try following code to reset the App's Permission Request XML in the link:

```
https://YourSharePointOnlineSiteUrl/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
```

Then request a new Access Token and try get the data again.